# what is a good introduction to AJAX in Ruby On Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I need some good introductory pointers to AJAX in the context of a Ruby On Rails app.

Here's the scoop: My app spins off several tasks using Delayed::Job.  While the tasks are busy [sprunging](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Sprunjer) data from external sites, I want to keep the user appraised of their progress.  I don't want to refresh the entire page -- just a rectangle on the page where each task can display status messages.

I don't believe I need a full push technology -- it is sufficient to use javascript-initiated polling to update the screen as long as bg tasks are running.

That's an appropriate scenario for AJAX (right?), and I think Rails3 has specific constructs to support AJAX-y interactions with browsers (right?).  Ryan Bates's [Railscast on Polling For Changes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/229-polling-for-changes) is a good template for this specific case, but I'd like a better understanding of what's really going on under the hood.  Okay, then where do I get started?

For what it's worth, I'm already using jQuery in my Rails3 app.

Comment: +1 for "sprunging".  It sounds like what might be looking for isn't just Ajax, but push, where the server sends information to the browser, as opposed to polling, where your app would periodically check for updates.  I don't know what the cool kids are using these days, but initial top googling turns up http://www.ape-project.org/

Comment: @numbers: thanks for the thoughtful reply, especially the heads-up that I'm asking about push technology.  Your response led me to http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/pusher (did I mention that I'm using heroku?  Oh, sorry...)  I'm still keen to learn the zen of AJAX, even for non-push.

Comment: @numbers: After nulling it over, I don't think I need full push technology and have amended the question to reflect that -- javascript initiated polling would be fine.  But I'm still looking for the real overview of what's going on between client and browser (especially in the Rails context).

Answer (score 2):

Just like numbersblah said you need a memory queue. Take a look at apache activemq. It might just do what you need.

Comment: +1 indeed, but I don't see how apache activemq or any memory queue gets me closer to an introduction to AJAX (even if part of my original question suggests I need a push technology).

Comment: No but what youre trying to achieve can be done simply by using a stomp client and use it to subscribe to a message from the active mq and based on it update your progress, that would be the trivial way of doing it.

Comment: @swordfish -- see the amended original question.  My sense is that push technology is overkill for this situation, thought it might be more elegant in the long run.

Comment: @fearless_fool You can use ajax for your scenario. In fact the even more simpler way to do that (not considering any performance issues) will be to update the status of the backend to a DB and use an ajax poller in a specified interval to poll the status from the db

Answer (score 1):

RailsCasts.com is a really great resource:

http://railscasts.com/episodes?utf8=%E2%9C%93&search=ajax

Comment: I suspect your response and my edit crossed paths -- I'm a big fan of RailsCasts.  (And points for that suggestion...)  But it still doesn't explain to me (for example) why rendering a foo.js.erb partial updates only part of the screen, and what mechanisms come to play to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

Rails Guides is another great resource: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html